# How to create a private route in react js using redux and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a issue in my github code that i dont know how to solve. I an new to redux and router v6. I am using typescript in my project and that is creating a bit more confusion, Can someone help me in solving this issue?

My issue is

Admin dashboard should only be accessed whenever the authorized user is logged in. But the route is being accessed publicly.

https://github.com/neeteshraj/finisterre-frontend/issues/1

This is my app.tsx file

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Home, Signup, Signin} from './container/index';
import './App.css';
import PrivateRoute from './components/common/HOC/Index';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"} element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
            <Route path={"/"} element={<Home/>} />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/signup"} element={<Signup/>}/>
          <Route path={"/signin"} element={<Signin/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}



export default App;
```

This is my privaterouter.tsx component

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes,Route, Navigate,useNavigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import authReducer from '../../../reducers/auth-reducers';



const PrivateRoute = (props:any) => {

    return (
        <Outlet {...props} component={(props:any)=>{
            const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
            if(token){
                return <props.component {...props}/>
            }
            else{
                return <Navigate to={`/signin`}/>
            }
        }}
        />
    )
}



export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help you if you don't post any of the code you need help with.

Comment: i tried posting it two times :( yet no one helped.

Comment: Where is the code posted at? There is no code posted in this question.

Comment: Could you paste the code here, rather than link to a Github? It would make answering your question much easier.

Comment: code pasted here. you can checkit out.

Comment: Are you going to have nested routes inside of your dashboard? I'm just trying to figure out whether or not you need to use the outlet component.

Comment: @SteveK i want to use nested routes

Comment: @niteshraj Dude read the answer I posted below. There is a version with and without nested routes. There is also a working codesandbox with 3 different files all that are working examples. Two of those are with nested routes. Read it over and if you still have questions let me know.

Comment: @SteveK i followed your method but the problem is the protected route is not rendering now when login is successful.

Comment: @niteshraj you need to set the token to a state or your component won't re render. If you are using redux you can just set it to a redux variable and use it in your PrivateRoute component.

Comment: @SteveK can you help me in it? I am having hard time solving this problem being a beginner.

Comment: @niteshraj here is a full project boilerplate with redux and react router. https://codesandbox.io/s/full-react-router-and-redux-boilerplate-in-typescript-dwdje and if the answer below satisfies then mark it as the correct answer. In the future consider being much more specific in your post https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and you will get better answers this is not a code writing service. Your post doesn't contain much relevant code and your link to your github is just a blank create-react-app template. If you have any questions please edit your post to contain what you need help with

Comment: @SteveK i fixed the problem thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well since I didn't know whether or not you wanted nested routes I figured I  would just help you out a little here. Since you didn't post anything related to redux I just left that out. Here is a working codesandbox with both nested and normal routes [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fix-react-router-v6-private-routes-r3wob).

In my examples below I am just using a working example so I am just using a state to control the token. You can sub in your `const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');` for that later but I wanted an example you could follow  along with easily. And since I don't know the extent of your code I figured it would be easier to just give you a working example.

Here is a normal example without nested routes:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Navigate,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

const Component: React.FC<{ title: string }> = ({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>;

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{ token: boolean }> = ({ token, children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return token ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  );
};

const Login: React.FC<{ setToken: any }> = ({ setToken }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location: any = useLocation();
  let from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setToken(true);
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  };

  return <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> | <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Component title="Home" />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login setToken={setToken} />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={
            <PrivateRoute token={token}>
              <Component title="Dashboard"/>
            </PrivateRoute>
          } />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So you can see that in the private route component we are checking for the token. If there is a token then we will just render the children otherwise we will navigate to the login page. In the login page we give the ability to login and then we will grab the location state and once logged in we will automatically redirect the person to the page they were trying to access.

Here is a nested route example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate
} from "react-router-dom";

const Component: React.FC<{ title: string }> = ({ title }) => <h1>{title}</h1>;

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{ token: boolean }> = ({ token, children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return token ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/dashboard/login" state={{ from: location }} />
  );
};

const Login: React.FC<{ setToken: any }> = ({ setToken }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location: any = useLocation();
  let from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";

  const handleLogin = () => {
    setToken(true);
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  };

  return <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>;
};

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> | <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Component title="Home" />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route
              path="/dashboard"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute token={token}>
                  <Component title="Dashboard" />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/dashboard/login"
              element={<Login setToken={setToken} />}
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here you can see that we are using the outlet as a placeholder in the Dashboard component. This lets react router know that we want to render some nested routes. If you want to nest your routes in the dashboard component then you don't need to use the outlet component you can just do:

```
const Dashboard: React.FC<{ token: boolean; setToken: any }> = ({
  token,
  setToken
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <PrivateRoute token={token}>
              <Component title="Dashboard" />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login setToken={setToken} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> | <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Component title="Home" />} />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard/*"
            element={ <Dashboard token={token} setToken={setToken} /> } />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```